# Differentiate $g(x)=(f(-\cos(x)))^3$

Tags: derivatives

Consider the function $g(x)=(f(-\cos(x)))^3$,

f(x) is unknown but differentiable.

Comment: Do you know the chain rule?

Comment: Yes, I do. (Ps thanks for edit)

Comment: Then apply it. Then you should get an expression for $g'(x)$ in terms of $f$ and its derivative

Comment: Hint: Define $y=-\cos(x)$

Comment: The first (outermost) operation you have is a cube. Derive the cube using the chain rule. You should have a $\frac{d}{dx}f(-\cos(x))$ in your answer; derive it using the chain rule again.

Comment: Think of it as $g(x)=h[f(y(x))]$ and apply the chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: By the chain rule,
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}p(q(r(x))) &= p'(q(r(x)) \frac{d}{dx}(q(r(x)))\\
&=p'(q(r(x)) q'(r(x))r'(x).
\end{align*}
Apply this for appropriate choices of the functions $p(x)$, $q(x)$, and $r(x)$.

Comment: Almost... you appear to be missing a derivative in the middle.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.